# JAVA: Using YouTube Live Streaming API to create new live event

Tags: java, youtube-api, wowza, youtube-livestreaming-api, wowza-transcoder

I want to create new live event in my youtube channel from Wowza Module, so I must to create it using Java. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this Wowza Support article for Wowza Streaming Engine, [How to stream to YouTube](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?542-How-to-stream-to-YouTube). It is no longer required to develop a Java module for this functionality. It is accessible through the Wowza Streaming Engine Manager UI.

If you want to do it programmatically, see the [push publishing API](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?109-How-to-push-streams-to-CDNs-and-other-services-(push-publishing)#api). Javadocs are included in the install in the documentation/serverapi folder.